# Округление числа до десятков и сотен

Tags: javascript

Я не знаю как написать код который будет округлять до десятков и сотен. Например у меня есть 365 и надо что бы его округляло к 370 или есть 350 и надо что бы округляло до 400

Comment: @MedvedevDev там в большую сторону округляет, возможно, конечно автору так и надо, но это не математическое округление

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Делаем на основе использования функции `Math.round`, которая округляет до целого.

```js
function MyRound10(val) {
  return Math.round(val / 10) * 10;
}

console.log(MyRound10(33));
console.log(MyRound10(36));
console.log(MyRound10(145));
```

Аналогичная функция для `100`.